# Pandas matching using .extract()

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to compare two .csv files. The first has a bunch of attributes deliberately separated into different columns. The second csv has all of those attributes combined in a single cell. I want to find a certain number of matches and, once confirmed, grab data from another cell (an image ID) in the second csv.

I am using pandas (new to it) and so far think extract/extractall is where I want to be. But in this basic test, I cannot see why I am not getting any matches.

```
image_index = pd.Series(['Classic', 'Duffle', 'Bag', 'Leather'])
image_index.str.extract('(?P<duffle>(?i)Duffle)(?P<bag>(?i)Bag)', expand=False)
```

Result:

```
  duffle  bag
0    NaN  NaN
1    NaN  NaN
2    NaN  NaN
3    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an alternation `|` between the groups since you only have each group pattern in one string:

```
>>> image_index.str.extract('(?P<duffle>(?i)Duffle)|(?P<bag>(?i)Bag)', expand=False)
   duffle  bag
0     NaN  NaN
1  Duffle  NaN
2     NaN  Bag
3     NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Why is that not required in the examples given in the docs? I don't see that in any of theirs. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: In the examples in the doc, the string has matches from both groups, but that is not the case here. If you had `DuffleBag` in the series, then your first regex will find a match.